# Why do I get undefined when displaying value in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just don't get it, obviously. I've tried setters and getters, self invoking functions, you name it. It's like the click handler is returning a value but there's no way for me to keep it?

This is my code in the first file request.js

```
var testId = (function (inId) {
    var citeId  = inId;
    return citeId;
})();

function mainAjax() {
   return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',                        
      url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?parentId=504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=60&offset=0&format=jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'jsonp'
   });
}

var promise = mainAjax();
```

this is the code in my second file requestMain.js,

```
promise.done(function (json) {
   var linkBase = "http://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/";
   var link = "";                     
   var itemId = "";                    
   var urlId = "";

   $.each(json.items, function(i,item) {
      link = linkBase + this.id;
      $('#sbItems').append('<li><b><a href="' + link + '" id="idNum' + i + ' ">' + this.title + '</a> - </b>' + this.summary + '</li>');                    
   });
   $('#sbItems a').on('click', function (e) {  
      e.preventDefault();                      
      var str = $(this).attr('id');                         
      if (str.length == 7) {                      
         itemId = str.slice(5,6);
      } 
      else if (str.length == 8) {
         itemId = str.slice(5,7);
      }
      testId = json.items[itemId].id;
      alert(testId);                      
}); // END Click event  

}).fail(function() {
   alert("Ajax call failed!");
});
```

This webpage displays a list of links. A link could have some more information that I want displayed on a second webpage or it could have nothing. So when a link is clicked I need to store/save/keep the id from the link so that I can use it in the url to make another ajax request, because until I get the id the ajax request for the next page will have no idea what information to ask for.

For now I'm simply doing this

```
alert(testId);
```

But what I'm trying to do is this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + testId + '?format=jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    // Then doing something with json.something
```

testId would be used in the url and it would change depending on the link that was clicked on the previous page. The ajax call is totally dependent on the click event and is displayed on a separate webpage with new information.

And this would be in my third file requestCitation.js which currently gives me a big undefined when doing

```
alert(testId);
```

I think this is a scope issue, but how can I store the value returned from a click??? So that I can then use it globally? It seems like the value disappears outside of the scope as if there was never a click at all even thought I'm storing it in a variable?

the html for the first page has script tags for request.js and requestMain.js and the second page has script tags for request.js and requestCitation.js, so they can both see the variable testId.

Thanks for the help!

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz5ZB/)

These are the links and when a link is clicked

Comment: Do you really indent your code like that is it a bad copy/paste?

Comment: `testID` is acquired asynchronously, right?  If that's the case, you can't depend on it being anywhere besides callbacks

Comment: Formatting code in posts isn't that convenient. I suggest posting a jsFiddle next time. :)

Comment: Sorry bad copy paste. Been pulling my hair out with this problem and think I'm just tired/ready to give up. You know when a question is just bugging you and you feel like you can't move on unless it's answered. That's me right now.

Comment: not a jquery user ( mootools myself ) but "var str = $(this).attr('id');", should there be $() round this ?

Comment: @ Will Klein, will do thanks. I did it once and someone didn't like that but I think I will do it anyway from now on. If it will help for this question I can put it in?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, ok and that's what I don't get? So if it's in the callback how would I go about doing that to get the value? Please excuse my ignorance as I'm still just learning all this!

Comment: Did it really: »alert("Ajax call failed!")«?

Comment: After relaying out your code there seems to be a couple of strange closing brackets? The `}` before the line commented `//End click event` doesn't seem needed and the that commented one is actually the end of the `promise.done()` function. And below that, before `.fail()` there is an extra `});`... please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @philipp, no it will display when the alert is called from within that javascript file. Meaning I have a html document that access that .js file and when I click a link it displays, However when I try to display it from another file it gives "undefined"??

Comment: @jc72 ajax callbacks all execute *after* the rest of all of your code.  Period.  You can't use the result of an ajax callback in "normal code," you have to do everything with callbacks

Comment: `var testId = (function (inId) {
    var citeId  = inId;
    return citeId;
})();` is absolutely equal to `var testId = void 0;`

Comment: @vletech my apologies your are absolutely correct I've had so much code in there I had to erase that I just let a few pieces I will correct

Comment: @Bergi had to look that up sorry, never heard of void 0? I'm looking to see how that works

Comment: @jc72: `void 0 === undefined`. I meant that this IEFE is absolutely useless.

Comment: Gotcha, then I guess I'm on a bad path to making this work. I have no idea how to go about doing this with javascript and jquery. In java I could get a value from a click or button or whatever and store it and use it. It seems a lot more difficult with javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `testId` is holding the value retuned by the function you're calling, and since the function returns its argument and you've called it without arguments, it will be `undefined`:

```
var testId = (function (inId) {
  var citeId  = inId;
  return citeId; //returns the argument
})(); // called with no argument
```

Comment: If I understand correctly then I would need to put the argument in when I do alert(testId); So then my logic is not going to work becuase I thought I could store the value from the click event doing testId = json.id or something like this and then use it somehow

Comment: In all likelihodd, what you want is possible and easy, but I think we've all struggled to understand what it is exactly, so what we're answering is why you're getting your `undefined`. Instead of providing code, could you try to itemise what you want to happen, i.e. what the initial state of things is, what should happen when you click a link, when should the ajax call be made, what should be the end result?

Comment: testid is redefined just before the alert in the anchors onclick handler.

Comment: @entonio, it seems like it would be easy but man this seems way over my head although I'm doing this just for learning experience. The way it should work is I have a set of links (for projects) that are displayed on a page (you can check the jfiddle to see them). When a link is clicked the next page will display some information about the link (project) and some citations, names. I've got everything working pretty much EXCEPT I cannot seem to display the information on the second page corresponding to the link that was clicked.

Comment: So if the first project link is clicked, then the second page would display information about that project along with it's specific citations and that would work for any link. I simply need to get the id which is done in the ('#sbItems') click to somehow go into the next ajax request for the next page, and I have no clue how to do it?

Comment: @Dampsquid so then it doesn't hold the value of id from the click handler, guess that won't work. Thanks for the info

Comment: @entonio I'm going to do like you said and just ask the question with no code, see if I can explain better. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but if you're trying to keep the data returned from the AJAX request as a global variable, I would have thought it was done using something similar to the below.

E.g.

```
var promise = '';
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',                        
      url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?parentId=504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=60&offset=0&format=jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'jsonp'
      data: '';
      success: function(data){
         promise = data;
      }
});
```

But as I said I'm not understanding fully so I could be very wrong with my answer.

Comment: Well something like this, and I know it's probably hard to understand becuase it seem comlicated at least to me. I want to first have a click handler $('#sbItems a').on('click', function (e) { // give me some stuff and then store that value, like testId = json.id; so that I can use this in another file.